# "Build only if SCM changes" is set to true in jenkins job but doesn't build with the latest commit

Tags: jenkins, build, version-control

I have a job **BuildApp** with a build (MultiJob Phase) that calls another job **BuildAppJar** to build a jar. In job **BuildApp**, "**Build only if SCM changes**" is set to true. I am expecting the job **BuildAppJar** will build a jar file with the latest commit because Job **BuildApp** is configured to build when SCM changes. But this is not happening. Instead I am getting this log saying "subjob has no changes since last build." Why is it so? Any idea? Isn't Jenkins supposed to build with the latest code commit? I am using Git.

```
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
    >> Job status: [BuildAppJar] subjob has no changes since last build.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because of this bug (I believe both are the same problem):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50168

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55524

The symptom is that Jenkins is polling two repositories, but doesn't check the correct one for changes.  Add your "git polling log" (or, depending on your plugin, whatever log appears at the bottom of the list above your build history) for confirmation.  I have not found a workaround.

Webhooks (gitlab, bitbucket, or whatever) don't actually cause Jenkins to build a particular commit - the webhook just notifies Jenkins that *something* has changes, and Jenkins polls the repository to see whether that change should trigger a build.  In my case, Jenkins receives the hook, polls the repo, then polls another repo (also used by that job, but rarely updated) and checks it for changes. So you need to have "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" and "Poll SCM" both checked.

For a long list of other possibilities, check 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17614

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using gitlab webhook so that whenever a push even occurs it will make a POST request to Jenkins to build BuildApp job. When I review gitlab's post request it is correct. As you pointed out the problem seems to be in jenkins. I am not sure if I understand the option "Build only if SCM changes". By the label I thought multi-job plugin checks git repo if there is any recent commit since the last build. But based on quick code review on multi-job plugin, it doesn't even check the git repo.

Comment: Answer updated with some stuff you probably already knew about webhooks and a couple of suggestions

Comment: Even after having both "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" and "Poll SCM" both checked, it didn't build a jor. As a workaround I have added a new stage in my pipeline to delete build history before building. Then it built a jar.

Answer (score 0):

It works! The problem is - Jenkins can't detect changes of subjob branch. You must perform, for each subjob, poll SCM or notify Jenkins by using WebHook.

Example of my usage with WebHook:

1. Install SCM Skip Plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/scmskip-plugin) to avoid automatic building after push to your branch.
2. In your subjob projects Configs:

   section **Build Triggers**:

   - check "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL:"
   - check "Poll SCM" (without schedule).
   - click on "Advanced" button and verify if option "Enable [ci-skip]" is checked (must be checked by default).

   section **Build Environment**:

   - check "SCM Skip".
3. Into GIT project, add WebHook located at **Settings** -> **WebHooks**.

   - put URL: `<jenkins_url>/gitlab/notify_commit`
   - check "Push events"
4. In Multijob Configs:

   section **Multijob specific configuration** :

   - check "Poll subjobs in addition to multijob when polling"

   section **Build Triggers**:

   - check "Poll SCM" (without schedule).
5. Commit you changes with message that contains word **[ci-skip]** to skip automatic build.

Now you can push changes to your branch, Jenkins will be notified and build skipped. After that, run your MultiJob.